# how to make a random generation number between 1 to 9 without repitition

Tags: c

i search about this issue in site and one of them help me a little.
i want to make a puzzle with random number between 1 to 9 and i use this method :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()  {
   int i = 1, num[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, k = 1;

   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      num[i] = i;
   }
   for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      int j = i + rand()%(10 - i);
      int temp = num[i];
      num[i] = num[j];
      num[j] = temp;

      if ((i - 1) % 3 == 0)
      {
         printf(" %i: ", k);
         k++;
      }


      printf(" %i", num[i]);

      if (i % 3 == 0)
      {
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

but i have a problem with this code.it makes the two last number same!!!
can any one help me ??

Comment: You're causing a stack corruption with your for loops.

Comment: As an aside (the currently accepted answer already deals with the main problem), how are you building your code? If you're compiling from the command line, you might benefit from cranking up warnings about buggy code. It'll save you time in the long run. ie: `gcc test.c -fstack-protector -Wall`, assuming your file is named `test.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a unique range of random numbers like this. It works by creating a pool of all the available numbers, selects one at random, and then removes that number from the pool. The same method could be used for dealing a deck of cards, without the need to explicitly shuffle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RANGE   9                   // range of numbers

int main() {
    int pool[RANGE];
    int size, n;
    for (size=0; size<RANGE; size++) {
        pool[size] = size+1;        // create number pool 1...
    }
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    while (size) {                  // generate random sequence
        n = rand() % size;          // random array index
        printf("%d ", pool[n]);     // select number from pool
        pool[n] = pool[--size];     // remove from pool
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here too is a debugged version of your program. Apart from bad array indexing, your mistake was to print from the array before the randomizing was finished.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()  {
    int i = 1, num[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        int j = rand() % 9;
        int temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[j];
        num[j] = temp;
    }

    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf("\n %d: ", 1+i/3);
        printf(" %i", num[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a shuffle, just not an in-place one.

Comment: Good answer! A minor comment I might add: when using this algorithm to "shuffle" a very large data set, the randomness of the shuffle is limited by the largest value `rand()` can return, and the quality of the shuffle. If you were to extend this algorithm to >1,000 elements for example, you'd likely want to replace the standard built-in `rand()` for a Mersenne Twister implementation. Aside of that, good work. Have an upvote!

Comment: @Dogbert thanks, and that's true. Another limitation *could* be an array holding every value for a large range.

Comment: i have another question about my puzzle project.
how can i put first random generation number in a array till to use statement to position numbers in the right situation ?

Comment: @aman I have added more to my answer, to shuffle the array and leave it available for use.

Answer (score 0):

@Weather Vane's answer is time efficient, but if you need to retain the random sequence, rather than simply output it, you would need a second array to copy the data to. The following shuffles the data "in-place":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void shuffle( int* pack, int length )
{
    int i ;

    // Initialise pack
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        pack[i] = i + 1 ;
    }

    // Swap random pairs
    for( i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        int n = rand() % length ;
        int m = rand() % length ;
        int h = pack[n] ;
        pack[n] = pack[m] ;
        pack[m] = h ;
    }
}

#define PACK_LENGTH 9 

int main(void) 
{
    int i ;
    int pack[PACK_LENGTH] ;

    srand( time(0) ) ;

    // Create and shuffle the pack
    shuffle( pack, pack_length ) ;

    // Print the pack
    for( i = 0; i < pack_length; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", pack[i] ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```