# Suggestion about unique values generation

Tags: c, random

I want to generate a series of "random" unique numbers, for use at a card game! These numbers should be between 0 and 81. 
I don't care about security or speed at this stage, i just want something simple to have the work done.

In my code below, i have managed to create 2 unique random numbers in the array that holds them, but the rest 10 numbers don't change but stay -1 that was the initial value..
I have found more accurate ways for random number generation, but i will check them out at a later stage!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int getRandomNumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    double rnd= (double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    return   (int)(rnd*(Max-Min+1))+Min;
}
int main()
{
    int j,counter,temp,deck[13];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    counter=1;
    for (i=0;i<12;i++)
        {deck[i]=-1;
        temp = getRandomNumber(0,81);

        for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {if (temp==deck[j])
                {counter=0;}
            if (counter!=0)
                deck[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        printf("%d ",deck[i]);

}
```

Comment: There is a vast number of questions here on SO about selecting a unique number. One method is to start with an array of available numbers, pick the *array index* at random, and remove that element from the array. Here is [one such answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867571/4142924).

Comment: If you already know the domain of your desired number set, (0..81), why not just load up a sequence of those 82 values, then do a simple [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on them.

Comment: the question says numbers BETWEEN 0 and 81 I.E. 1...80.  You can use this statement: `value = (rand() %80) +1;`,  If you do not want any repeated numbers, then with each new 'value', search the array to assure it is not already in the array before inserting the new 'value' into the array.

Comment: Well, I am required to use rand to create these values! With value=(rand()%80) +1; am I getting not repeated values?

Comment: @user3629249: if you code SQL, the `x BETWEEN y AND z` operator includes the end points in the range (`x >= y AND x <= z`).  In plain English, it is not clear that 'between … and' excludes the end points.  Certainly, in the subtly different 'between you and me' phrase, the two people are included; if you say "choose a number between 1 and 100", you won't normally be upset by the choice of 1 or 100.  You might critique the question for ambiguity, but it is not clear that 'between 0 and 81' automatically excludes both 0 and 81.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  as an example, if there are two side walks, with a road 'between' them, then when discussing the road, that side walks are not part of the discussion.  If you really want to include the end points use the word 'inclusive' not 'between'.   Also, the syntax of SQL has nothing to do with the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has one of the weirder indentation and brace layout schemes I've ever seen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getRandomNumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    double rnd= (double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    return   (int)(rnd*(Max-Min+1))+Min;
}

int main()
{
    int j,counter,temp,deck[13];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    counter=1;
    for (i=0;i<12;i++)
        {deck[i]=-1;
        temp = getRandomNumber(0,81);

        for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {if (temp==deck[j])
                {counter=0;}
            if (counter!=0)
                deck[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
        printf("%d ",deck[i]);

}
```

Converted to a more orthodox style (Allman, more or less — see Wikipedia on [Indent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)), you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int getRandomNumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    double rnd = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    return (int)(rnd * (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
}

int main(void)
{
    int j, counter, temp, deck[13];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    counter = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = -1;
        temp = getRandomNumber(0, 81);

        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (temp == deck[j])
            {
                counter = 0;
            }
            if (counter != 0)
                deck[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("%d ", deck[i]);
}
```

The `static` and `int main(void)` are needed to get the code past my default compilation options; otherwise, they're cosmetic.

Now we can see some problems.  The `counter` is set to `1` once, outside the outer loop; it is set to `0` sometimes inside the loop, but once that happens, it is never reset to `1`, so no further numbers are added to the `deck`.  You need to rework the inner loop, maybe like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int getRandomNumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    double rnd = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    return (int)(rnd * (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
}

int main(void)
{
    int deck[13];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int temp = getRandomNumber(0, 81);
        deck[i] = -1;

        int counter = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (temp == deck[j])
            {
                counter = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (counter != 0)
            deck[i] = temp;
        else
            i--;  // Try again with a new random choice for the same i
    }
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%d", pad, deck[i]);
        pad = " ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

I dislike trailing blanks, so the printing loop takes care to ensure there aren't any.

Sample output with `getRandomNumber()` — on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 with GCC 6.3.0:

```
7 73 38 61 11 13 41 66 29 39 72 20
7 2 18 17 54 31 45 40 34 22 63 16
7 13 80 54 16 49 14 58 28 53 23 26
7 24 60 10 67 53 69 32 23 2 66 12
7 34 40 48 21 3 57 43 6 18 27 80
7 45 20 3 65 21 61 17 12 69 66 27
7 67 62 78 70 57 68 46 9 2 72 39
7 77 41 34 32 75 72 20 64 78 33 25
7 6 21 72 76 11 75 38 73 27 64 33
7 17 1 27 37 28 80 49 12 67 59 36
```

That first number isn't very random — shortly after that sequence of tests, it changed from 7 to 8, but was equally non-random.  An alternative
way of generating random numbers is:

```
static int getRandomNumber(int Min, int Max)
{
    int rnd;
    int range = (Max - Min + 1);

    while ((rnd = rand()) > RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % range))
        ;

    return (rnd % range) + Min;
}
```

This avoids the bias from that fact that 82 doesn't divide RAND_MAX exactly, which would weight the distribution of the lower numbers slightly higher than the upper numbers in the range 0..81.  It also avoids the unexpectedly consistent first number, though the new first number is also semi-predictable when the tests are run at 1-second intervals.

Sample results:

```
48 33 28 78 14 2 81 13 23 75 38 40
45 42 74 1 11 68 17 33 78 49 23 80
42 51 38 3 5 52 35 56 54 23 59 41
39 60 2 8 36 53 79 30 72 75 62 37
36 69 45 10 78 20 71 17 6 53 54 30
33 78 9 15 75 7 40 61 27 36 70 68
30 5 55 17 69 73 25 63 37 1 21 71
27 14 19 66 57 43 1 13 3 65 71 21
24 26 62 63 41 61 68 28 67 20 74 17
21 35 26 57 28 79 47 44 2 52 60 77
```

Notice that the first number decreases by 3; the second seems to increase by 9; ugh — the randomness isn't all that good. It's well known that `rand()` is often not a high quality PRNG (pseudo-random number generator), but I'm a little surprised by this apparently systematic behaviour with seeds that differ by 1 each time.

On my Mac, when I changed `srand()` to `srandom()` and `rand()` to `random()`, I got better (as in, more unpredictable) results:

```
29 1 7 11 25 52 63 15 26 55 75 64
40 4 64 18 8 57 73 27 38 15 60 28
43 3 27 17 1 58 26 72 73 18 20 7
76 16 27 43 64 20 63 30 35 17 33 57
79 47 32 33 6 30 35 7 38 55 25 61
69 57 79 75 15 54 5 35 21 46 65 61
30 79 66 14 56 39 19 8 50 47 76 33
62 65 81 44 52 39 25 30 54 12 24 68
27 49 60 72 53 35 14 41 63 46 45 65
67 39 9 11 60 19 64 73 43 17 21 26
```

And the Mac man page for `random()` still suggests using `arc4random()` instead, but this is a lot better than plain `rand()`.  What you find on other systems will depend on the facilities provided by the system — `rand()` may not be as awful as it seems to be on Mac.  Basically, be cautious with your choice of PRNG — especially if you're going to use systematically generated seeds (such as the current time).

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you propose (generating a "random" sequence of numbers ranging from 0 through 81, where each item differs from the others), consider this: if a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) admits fewer than 82-factorial seeds, then there are some permutations of an eighty-two-item list that that PRNG can't choose when it shuffles that list.

However, the C `rand()` function's implementation is unspecified, so is not guaranteed to choose that many permutations.

A PRNG can't choose from among more pseudorandom number sequences than the number of seeds it admits. For `82!` permutations, no PRNG that admits fewer than `82!` seeds (and thus no PRNG with a state size of less than 408 bits, since the next highest power of 2 is 2<sup>408</sup>) can do this -- and 51 bytes is much bigger than `srand` can usually take. (Nothing is said here about PRNGs that admit as many or more seeds than the number of permutations or whether the permutations the PRNG *can* choose have an equal probability of occurring, as opposed to an ideal process of generating *perfectly* independent uniform random integers.)

See "Shuffling" in [my article on randomness](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html) for more information.